# Strange Ajax behavior in JQuery in Opera and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, opera

I have this functions

```
//send JSON-RPC request
var json_rpc = (function() {
    var id = 1;
    return function(url, method, params, success) {

        if (typeOf(params) != 'array') {
            params = [params];
        }
        var request = JSON.stringify({
                       'jsonrpc': '2.0',
                       'method': method, 
                       'params': params, 
                       'id': id++});
        return $.ajax({
            url: url, 
            data: request,
            success: success,
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  error_msg('XHR error ' + XMLHttpRequest.status + ' ' +
                     XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
       console.log('before send');
       console.log(dir(xhr));
       xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
          console.log('state');
      };
        },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type:"POST"});
    }
})();
```

```
var rpc = function(method, success_callback) {
    //I use functional javascript library
    var fun = json_rpc.partial('rpc.php', method, _, function(data) {
        if (data['error']) {
            var e = 'Json-RPC (' + method + ') ' + data['error']['code'] + ": " + 
               data['error']['message'];
            error_msg(e);
        } else {
            info_msg("rpc sucess for method '" + method + "'");
            success_callback(data['result']);
        }
    });
    return function() {
        fun(Array.slice(arguments));
    };
};
```

and when I create function with rpc

```
var update_news = rpc('get_news', function(data) {
    if (data) {
       //update news
    }
});
```

and call it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
    update_news();
    ...
});
```

In Firefox everythig is fine, but in Opera and Chrome the function `update_news` is not executing, `beforeSend` is fired but `onreadystatechange` is not, but when I add

```
setTimeout(update_news, 0);
```

Then It's call normaly, also when I create synchronous call by putting `async: false` in `$.ajax` call or when I put timeout, `timeout: 1`. In click handlers it also run as expected.

```
$('#some_id').click(function() {
  update_news();
});
```

Anybody know why this is happening.

Comment: Did you forget `var` in the first function for the "request" variable?

Comment: I change it and it's act the same.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's error console?

Comment: also, it would be easier to help you if you could link to a demo

Comment: No errors just function `update_news()` didn't fire.

Comment: do you still have the issue, did you find a way to solve it? If yes could you put an answer on the post.

Comment: @karlcow I give it up, maybe I will try again to debug this application. If I find solution, I will post the answer.

Comment: do you think you could put a short example on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The problem was with lwRTE jquery plugin (HTML Editor)